# How to show SaveFileDialog

Tags: asp.net

How to show `SaveFileDialog` to user that can select path for save file?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that in Web pages.

You have to do "save file as.." check [Link](http://aspalliance.com/259)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot show `SaveFileDialog` in the `ASP.net` code because it is executed on the **server side**. 
Normally in such cases, flush the files/ images as bytes and a dialog appears to the user either to open it or save it on their machine.